# Refresh token for desktop application without a login prompt consuming Web Api 2.0 with oAuth

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I have a web api 2.0 and a winform application. I am in the process of securing my web api. What I have implemented so far is that I have saved a usercode and an encrypted password in the winform app configuration file. Using those as username and password, I am able to retrieve a token to communicate with the API. Now I am trying to implement a Refresh Token and have come across a number of questions:

Is **Refresh Token** the right idea for a **desktop application without login prompt**?

- If yes, does it need to be done using the **Client Credentials (id and secret)**?

  - If yes, how to create and store the client id and secret in the client side?
  - If no, is there a tutorial or example how to achieve refresh token without client id and secret?
- If no, should I make the token long lived?

Comment: This winform app is external ( used by unknown users ) or internal ( eg. used by your organizations members ) ?

Comment: It is external but used one copy per organization.

Comment: It is possible that who use the app authenticate for their own ?

Comment: Per organization yes, but not per user.

Comment: Do you have some vpn ?

Answer (score 0):

With oauth2, after a client successfully authenticates, the authentication server issues an `access_token`, `refresh_token`, and `token_expiration`. The `access_token` is used for authorizing requests while the `refresh_token` is used for requesting a new `access_token` and `refresh_token` without needing the client to authenticate again.

In most cases, these tokens are returned in a JSON response. For posting your authentication request to your authentication server, it will depend on your implementation. With token persistence, you can decide if you want to keep the token saved to disk or to application memory. After the token expires, you can then have your application request a new set of tokens.